Two column linenumbers in outer margin does not work with Revtex4-2
If I use lineno with the switch option in \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}, the output is what I would expect, the line numbers appear on the outer margins.

But, using
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}

I am presented with this mess,

I have even tried using,
\RequirePackage[switch]{lineno}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

and compiled the document a couple of times, but still, it did not work.
